# How to write select queries for paginating output from ManyToMany attributes

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa

I have a Group table with ManyToMany relationship with the User table via a join table. A Group could contain a lot of users or could contain sub groups containing more users.

I am using JPA, Hibernate 3.3

1. How do I paginate the results returned by Group.getUsers() which could be either users obtained via Group.getUsers OR could be all users from the subgroups in Group.getGroups

Note: Since I have expressed this as a ManyToMany relationship, I don't have an entity table (for the join table) and not sure how to perform any queries using JPA on the join table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = "255", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "group_user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(0);

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "group_subgroup", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "src_group_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "target_group_id"))
private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>(0);
```

Comment: did you have any success? did you see my last update?

Comment: still working on it, seems to be fine so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `private List<Group> groups` (lazy) in the user entity. And have, for the groups:

```
`SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.groups g WHERE g=:group`
```

and for the subgroups:

```
`SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.groups WHERE g IN (:groups)`
```

(and call `query.setParameter("groups", group.getGroups())`)

Comment: @Bozho - The link table group_user contains all users belonging to a particular group. It's not clear on your approach why you are expecting a group parameter to be assigned to the user table. If you look at the table definition, the join table is automatically created by hbm2ddl and the link table is not annotated with the @Entity annotation. So, I am not sure how to run queries on this link table.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the many-to-many. Don't think in terms of relational schema. Think in terms if your objects.